# How to merge this two recursive function into one function?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static int countWord(String string)
{
    if (string == null || string.equals(""))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + countWord(string.substring(1));
    }
}

public static int countSent(String sentence)
{
    int i = sentence.indexOf(' ');
    if (i == -1) return 1;                          //Space is not found
    return 1 + countSent(sentence.substring(i+1));
}
```

can someone help me make this into one function 
if a user enter a word it should count the letters and if the user enters a sentence it should count the words in a sentence

example

```
Input: Apple
Output: 5

Input: apple is red
output: 3
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Do you have to use recursion? Your requirement can easily be achieved without recursion.

Comment: sadly yes i need to use recursion im using java i already made a program that uses this two functions but the instructions said that i have to make a recursive function

Answer (score 0):

Seems kind of like a cop-out, but if it needs to be a single function call, just write a count function and then call the appropriate recursive sub-function.  For example:

```
public static int count(String input)
{
    if (input.indexOf(' ') == -1)
    {
        return countWord(input);
    }
    return countSent(input);
}
```